# Why isn't my javascript working ? (html5 game dev

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've trying to find my mistake(s) for over an hour now and I cannot figure out why the story isn't being output. This tutorial is from "HTML5 game development for dummies" and it looks like I've copied the examples exactly but it still isn't working

```
CSS: http://pastebin.com/DngEJh4t
JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/hvq3Sukg
```

HTML file as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>wordstory.html</title>
        <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href ="wordStory.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript" src = "wordStory.js">
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Word Story</h1>
    <form action=" ">
        <fieldset>
            <label for = "txtBoy">Boy's name</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtBoy" />

            <label for = "txtGirl">Girl's name</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtGirl" />

            <label for = "txtGeol">Geological formation</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtGeol" />

            <label for = "txtVerb">Verb</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtVerb" />

            <label for = "txtContainer">Container</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtContainer" />

            <label for = "txtLiquid">Liquid</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtliquid" />

            <label for = "txtPart">Body Part</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "txtPart" />

            <label for = "txtGerund">ing Verb</label>
            <input type = "text" id = "textGerund" />

            <button type = "button" onclick = "tellStory()">
                tell the story
            </button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
    <div id = "output"></div>       
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Show us your javascript code please.

Comment: Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Ensure that the [**full minimal**](/help/mcve) code for your question goes **in** your question (not just linked). Ideally, use the `<>` button to create a *runnable* version of your code here on site.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki it's in the pastebin link at the top of the question

Comment: `it's in the pastebin link at the top of the question` - there is no spoon ... I mean pasebin link

Comment: @sudoslayen.dev - you should edit the Javascript (and CSS) into your question (instead of linking it - linking is discouraged because it relies on the linked to site being up, it being reliable, etc.)

Comment: @JaromandaX `CSS: http://pastebin.com/DngEJh4t
JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/hvq3Sukg` ;) Although I agree it should be in the question!

Comment: lol, I had the code section scrolled down to the bottom :D

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone it was my first question here, I'll keep everything in mind next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id = "txtliquid"` should be `id = "txtLiquid"` and `id = "textGerund"` should be `id = "txtGerund"`.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/60f562kL/